# How do I append an element after a specific element using jquery with an object as the target?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, element

I want to append an element of H2 `<h2>H2</h2>` to the html as shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="a">
        <h1>H1</h1>
        <!--I want to add H2 here-->
        <h3>H3</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="b">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I query the div like this `var mydiv = $("#a")[0];` and then I want to append `<h2>H2</h2>` inside myDiv, but after `<h1>H1</h1>` OR before `<h3>H3</h3>`. I have played around a bit with after(), insertAfter(), before(), insertBefore() with no luck, because i want to target and use the object 'myDiv' and not the whole html page.

**EDIT:** Some things I have tried

I have tried the following:

```
var myDiv = $("#a")[0]
$(myDiv).append("<h2>H2</h2>")
```

This adds the element to the end of the div

Also tried this:

```
$("h1").after("<h2>H2</h2>")
```

This adds `<h2>H2</h2>` after every `<h1>H1</h1>` which is not what I need to do, I need to add `<h2>H2</h2>` only inside the selected div which in this case is `myDiv`

Comment: Always show what you have tried that isn't working

Comment: I have edited now with some things I have tried, problem is the target. I want to target the slected div and not thw whole html page. Thi is a sample, in the real html page I have multiple H1s and using after would ad H2s after every H1, same with before() and H3s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`jQuery#after`](https://api.jquery.com/after/) and [`jQuery#find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```js
var myDiv = $("#a")[0];
$(myDiv).find('h1').after("<h2>H2</h2>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">
  <h1>H1</h1>
  <!--I want to add H2 here-->
  <h3>H3</h3>
</div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

or

```
$("#a").find("h1").after("<h2>H2</h2>");
```

or

```
$("#a h1").after("<h2>H2</h2>");
```

Comment: Hey, that slector made the difference.. is there a way instead of using `$('#a h1')` to somehow target h1 but using an exisitng object, like `myDiv` I have in the example?

Comment: @user2052544 you need to use `find` or something similar, check updated answer

Comment: Had no idea we can chain an `after()` after a `find()`... always learning. Great, tried it with actual html I have and worked as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, only need change the selector adding h1 in the myDiv selector.

Example:

`var myDiv = $("#a h1")[0]
$(myDiv).after("<h2>H2</h2>")`

Comment: append() adds the element in the end and prepend() in the beginning. Had tried this and is not what I wanted. I have accepted a previous answer as correct, have a look please.

Comment: Sorry, I read your last piece of code and thought that it would put "after" instead of "append". Edited.